# Missing Called-Station-Id parameter in "Accounting-Request" FreeRadius UniFi

Tags: freeradius

I'm having trouble inserting the "Called-Station-Id" parameter into the radacct table.

After connecting to Unifi (AP AC LITE) in "Access-Request" I get the parameter Called-Station-Id.

However, "Access-Request" is followed by "Accounting-Request" in which the Called-Station-Id parameter is empty. The Called-Staion-Id field in the radacct table is empty.

Could someone tell me why this is happening and how could I insert the Called-Station-Id parameter into the radacct table?

I also use microTik access points and they insert the Called-Station-Id parameter into the radacct table

Below I pasted the radius logs that show "Access-Request" (1) and "Accounting-Request" (2):

```
(1) Received Access-Request Id 30 from 185.13.190.143:60381 to 148.252.41.12:1812 length 213
(1)  Called-Station-Id = "B4-FB-E4-10-52-47:Hotspot Test"
(1)  Calling-Station-Id = "C4-B3-01-5B-E3-79"
(1)  Acct-Session-Id = "3dr3mfty1bltwpg4"
(1)  NAS-Identifier = "32296af2-4c7c-4492-a02c-9dff3298503d"
(1)  NAS-IP-Address = 10.255.0.104
(1)  Framed-IP-Address = 178.37.87.66
(1)  User-Name = "c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79"
(1)  CHAP-Challenge = 0xfe51d128a7fa49f20a684cb62b33d2cf
(1)  CHAP-Password = 0x26b5e87d6e3ae20e0c9f9b7ec1f3ba1050
(1)  Message-Authenticator = 0x7b2188c4c44c830131d8c6a4d606c36e
(1) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(1)  authorize {
(1)   policy filter_username {
(1)    if (&User-Name) {
(1)    if (&User-Name) -> TRUE
(1)    if (&User-Name) {
(1)     if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(1)     if (&User-Name =~ / /) -> FALSE
(1)     if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {
(1)     if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) -> FALSE
(1)     if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(1)     if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) -> FALSE
(1)     if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/)) {
(1)     if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  -> FALSE
(1)     if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/) {
(1)     if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  -> FALSE
(1)     if (&User-Name =~ /@\./) {
(1)     if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  -> FALSE
(1)    } # if (&User-Name) = notfound
(1)   } # policy filter_username = notfound
(1)   [preprocess] = ok
(1)   policy rewrite_called_station_id {
(1)    if (&Called-Station-Id && (&Called-Station-Id =~ /^([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})([^0-9a-f](.+))?$/i)) {
(1)    if (&Called-Station-Id && (&Called-Station-Id =~ /^([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})([^0-9a-f](.+))?$/i)) -> TRUE
(1)    if (&Called-Station-Id && (&Called-Station-Id =~ /^([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})([^0-9a-f](.+))?$/i)) {
(1)     update request {
(1)      EXPAND %{toupper:%{1}:%{2}:%{3}:%{4}:%{5}:%{6}}
(1)       --> B4:FB:E4:10:52:47
(1)      &Called-Station-Id := B4:FB:E4:10:52:47
(1)     } # update request = noop
(1)     if ("%{8}") {
(1)     EXPAND %{8}
(1)      --> Hotspot Test
(1)     if ("%{8}") -> TRUE
(1)     if ("%{8}") {
(1)      update request {
(1)       EXPAND %{8}
(1)        --> Hotspot Test
(1)       &Called-Station-SSID := Hotspot Test
(1)      } # update request = noop
(1)     } # if ("%{8}") = noop
(1)     [updated] = updated
(1)    } # if (&Called-Station-Id && (&Called-Station-Id =~ /^([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})([^0-9a-f](.+))?$/i)) = updated
(1)    ... skipping else: Preceding "if" was taken
(1)   } # policy rewrite_called_station_id = updated
(1)   policy rewrite_calling_station_id {
(1)    if (&Calling-Station-Id && (&Calling-Station-Id =~ /^([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})$/i)) {
(1)    if (&Calling-Station-Id && (&Calling-Station-Id =~ /^([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})$/i)) -> TRUE
(1)    if (&Calling-Station-Id && (&Calling-Station-Id =~ /^([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})$/i)) {
(1)     update request {
(1)      EXPAND %{toupper:%{1}:%{2}:%{3}:%{4}:%{5}:%{6}}
(1)       --> C4:B3:01:5B:E3:79
(1)      &Calling-Station-Id := C4:B3:01:5B:E3:79
(1)     } # update request = noop
(1)     [updated] = updated
(1)    } # if (&Calling-Station-Id && (&Calling-Station-Id =~ /^([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})$/i)) = updated
(1)    ... skipping else: Preceding "if" was taken
(1)   } # policy rewrite_calling_station_id = updated
(1) chap:  &control:Auth-Type := CHAP
(1)   [chap] = ok
(1)   [mschap] = noop
(1)   [digest] = noop
(1) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(1) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79", looking up realm NULL
(1) suffix: No such realm "NULL"
(1)   [suffix] = noop
(1) eap: No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
(1)   [eap] = noop
(1)   [files] = noop
(1) sql: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(1) sql:  --> c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79
(1) sql: SQL-User-Name set to 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79'
rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (6)
(1) sql: EXPAND SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id
(1) sql:  --> SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79' ORDER BY id(1) sql: Executing select query: SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79' ORDER BY id
(1) sql: User found in radcheck table
(1) sql: Conditional check items matched, merging assignment check items
(1) sql:  Cleartext-Password := "c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79"
(1) sql: EXPAND SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radreply WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id
(1) sql:  --> SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radreply WHERE username = 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79' ORDER BY id(1) sql: Executing select query: SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radreply WHERE username = 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79' ORDER BY id
(1) sql: EXPAND SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY priority
(1) sql:  --> SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79' ORDER BY priority
(1) sql: Executing select query: SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79' ORDER BY priority
(1) sql: User not found in any groups
rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (6)
Need 1 more connections to reach min connections (3)
rlm_sql (sql): Opening additional connection (7), 1 of 30 pending slots used
rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
rlm_sql_mysql: Connected to database 'radius' on Localhost via UNIX socket, server version 5.7.22, protocol version 10
(1)   [sql] = ok
(1)   [expiration] = noop
(1)   [logintime] = noop
(1) pap: WARNING: Auth-Type already set. Not setting to PAP
(1)   [pap] = noop
(1)  } # authorize = updated
(1) Found Auth-Type = CHAP
(1) # Executing group from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(1)  Auth-Type CHAP {
(1) chap: Comparing with "known good" Cleartext-Password
(1) chap: CHAP user "c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79" authenticated successfully
(1)   [chap] = ok
(1)  } # Auth-Type CHAP = ok
(1) # Executing section post-auth from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(1)  post-auth {
(1)   update {
(1)    No attributes updated
(1)   } # update = noop
(1) sql: EXPAND .query
(1) sql:  --> .query
(1) sql: Using query template 'query'
rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (5)
(1) sql: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(1) sql:  --> c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79
(1) sql: SQL-User-Name set to 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79'
(1) sql: EXPAND INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate) VALUES ( '%{SQL-User-Name}', '%{%{User-Password}:-%{Chap-Password}}', '%{reply:Packet-Type}', '%S')
(1) sql:  --> INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate) VALUES ( 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79', '0x26b5e87d6e3ae20e0c9f9b7ec1f3ba1050', 'Access-Accept', '2019-12-12 09:51:11.859278')
(1) sql: Executing query: INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate) VALUES ( 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79', '0x26b5e87d6e3ae20e0c9f9b7ec1f3ba1050', 'Access-Accept', '2019-12-12 09:51:11.859278')
(1) sql: SQL query returned: success
(1) sql: 1 record(s) updated
rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (5)
(1)   [sql] = ok
(1)   [exec] = noop
(1)   policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(1)    if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
(1)    if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) -> FALSE
(1)    else {
(1)     [noop] = noop
(1)    } # else = noop
(1)   } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(1)  } # post-auth = ok
(1) Sent Access-Accept Id 30 from 148.252.41.12:1812 to 185.13.190.143:60381 length 0
(1) Finished request
Waking up in 0.7 seconds.
(2) Received Accounting-Request Id 112 from 185.13.190.143:47776 to 148.252.41.12:1813 length 69
(2)  User-Name = "c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79"
(2)  Acct-Session-Id = "3dr3mfty1bltwpg4"
(2)  Acct-Status-Type = Start
(2)  Event-Timestamp = "Dec 12 2019 09:51:12 EST"
(2) # Executing section preacct from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(2)  preacct {
(2)   [preprocess] = ok
(2)   policy rewrite_called_station_id {
(2)    if (&Called-Station-Id && (&Called-Station-Id =~ /^([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})([^0-9a-f](.+))?$/i)) {
(2)    if (&Called-Station-Id && (&Called-Station-Id =~ /^([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})([^0-9a-f](.+))?$/i)) -> FALSE
(2)    else {
(2)     [noop] = noop
(2)    } # else = noop
(2)   } # policy rewrite_called_station_id = noop
(2)   policy rewrite_calling_station_id {
(2)    if (&Calling-Station-Id && (&Calling-Station-Id =~ /^([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})$/i)) {
(2)    if (&Calling-Station-Id && (&Calling-Station-Id =~ /^([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})[^0-9a-f]?([0-9a-f]{2})$/i)) -> FALSE
(2)    else {
(2)     [noop] = noop
(2)    } # else = noop
(2)   } # policy rewrite_calling_station_id = noop
(2)   policy acct_unique {
(2)    update request {
(2)     &Tmp-String-9 := "ai:"
(2)    } # update request = noop
(2)    if (("%{hex:&Class}" =~ /^%{hex:&Tmp-String-9}/) &&    ("%{string:&Class}" =~ /^ai:([0-9a-f]{32})/i)) {
(2)    EXPAND %{hex:&Class}
(2)     -->
(2)    EXPAND ^%{hex:&Tmp-String-9}
(2)     --> ^61693a
(2)    if (("%{hex:&Class}" =~ /^%{hex:&Tmp-String-9}/) &&    ("%{string:&Class}" =~ /^ai:([0-9a-f]{32})/i)) -> FALSE
(2)    else {
(2)     update request {
(2)      EXPAND %{md5:%{User-Name},%{Acct-Session-ID},%{%{NAS-IPv6-Address}:-%{NAS-IP-Address}},%{NAS-Identifier},%{NAS-Port-ID},%{NAS-Port}}
(2)       --> 7db92fee37429b54c2a5c4d942df0351
(2)      &Acct-Unique-Session-Id := 7db92fee37429b54c2a5c4d942df0351
(2)     } # update request = noop
(2)    } # else = noop
(2)   } # policy acct_unique = noop
(2) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(2) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79", looking up realm NULL
(2) suffix: No such realm "NULL"
(2)   [suffix] = noop
(2)   [files] = noop
(2)  } # preacct = ok
(2) # Executing section accounting from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(2)  accounting {
(2) detail: EXPAND /var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d
(2) detail:  --> /var/log/radius/radacct/185.13.190.143/detail-20191212
(2) detail: /var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d expands to /var/log/radius/radacct/185.13.190.143/detail-20191212
(2) detail: EXPAND %t
(2) detail:  --> Thu Dec 12 09:51:11 2019
(2)   [detail] = ok
(2)   [unix] = ok
(2) sql: EXPAND %{tolower:type.%{Acct-Status-Type}.query}
(2) sql:  --> type.start.query
(2) sql: Using query template 'query'
rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (6)
(2) sql: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(2) sql:  --> c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79
(2) sql: SQL-User-Name set to 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79'
(2) sql: EXPAND INSERT INTO radacct (acctsessionid,       acctuniqueid,      username, realm,
    nasipaddress,      nasportid, nasporttype,     acctstarttime,     acctupdatetime, acctstoptime,
    acctsessiontime,    acctauthentic, connectinfo_start,    connectinfo_stop,    acctinputoctets, acctoutputoctets,   calledstationid,    callingstationid, acctterminatecause,  servicetype,      framedprotocol, framedipaddress) VALUES ('%{Acct-Session-Id}', '%{Acct-Unique-Session-Id}', '%{SQL-User-Name}', '%{Realm}', '%{NAS-IP-Address}', '%{%{NAS-Port-ID}:-%{NAS-Port}}', '%{NAS-Port-Type}', FROM_UNIXTIME(%{integer:Event-Timestamp}), FROM_UNIXTIME(%{integer:Event-Timestamp}), NULL, '0', '%{Acct-Authentic}', '%{Connect-Info}', '', '0', '0', '%{Called-Station-ID}', '%{Calling-Station-ID}', '', '%{Service-Type}', '%{Framed-Protocol}', '%{Framed-IP-Address}')
(2) sql:  --> INSERT INTO radacct (acctsessionid,       acctuniqueid,      username, realm,
    nasipaddress,      nasportid, nasporttype,     acctstarttime,     acctupdatetime, acctstoptime,
    acctsessiontime,    acctauthentic, connectinfo_start,    connectinfo_stop,    acctinputoctets, acctoutputoctets,   calledstationid,    callingstationid, acctterminatecause,  servicetype,      framedprotocol, framedipaddress) VALUES ('3dr3mfty1bltwpg4', '7db92fee37429b54c2a5c4d942df0351', 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79', '', '185.13.190.143', '', '', FROM_UNIXTIME(1576162272), FROM_UNIXTIME(1576162272), NULL, '0', '', '', '', '0', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '')
(2) sql: Executing query: INSERT INTO radacct (acctsessionid,      acctuniqueid,      username, realm,
        nasipaddress,      nasportid, nasporttype,     acctstarttime,     acctupdatetime, acctstoptime,      acctsessiontime,    acctauthentic, connectinfo_start,    connectinfo_stop,    acctinputoctets, acctoutputoctets,   calledstationid,    callingstationid, acctterminatecause,  servicetype,      framedprotocol, framedipaddress) VALUES ('3dr3mfty1bltwpg4', '7db92fee37429b54c2a5c4d942df0351', 'c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79', '', '185.13.190.143', '', '', FROM_UNIXTIME(1576162272), FROM_UNIXTIME(1576162272), NULL, '0', '', '', '', '0', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '')
(2) sql: SQL query returned: success
(2) sql: 1 record(s) updated
rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (6)
(2)   [sql] = ok
(2)   [exec] = noop
(2) attr_filter.accounting_response: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(2) attr_filter.accounting_response:  --> c4:b3:01:5b:e3:79
(2) attr_filter.accounting_response: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 12
(2)   [attr_filter.accounting_response] = updated
(2)  } # accounting = updated
(2) Sent Accounting-Response Id 112 from 148.252.41.12:1813 to 185.13.190.143:47776 length 0
(2) Finished request
(2) Cleaning up request packet ID 112 with timestamp +67
Waking up in 0.7 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than asking Ubiquiti to fix the issue, the only other thing you could try is returning the Called-Station-ID value in the Class attribute.  NAS are meant to return this value in the next Accounting-Request, but not all do.

```
post-auth {
    update reply {
        Class := "%{Called-Station-ID}"
    }

}
```

```
preacct {
    if (!&Called-Station-ID && &Class) {
        update request {
            Called-Station-ID := "%{string:Class}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately, the parameter I need is "Called-Station-Id" (mac address of the access point).

And the example you show fills in the parameter "Calling-Station-Id" (user's mac address). 
Do you know how I could fill in the "Called-Station-Id" parameter?

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread.   Changed the answer for Called-Station-ID.  What I've suggested _may_ work, but it's not guaranteed to. YMMV

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The Class parameter in preacct is empty :(

Comment: Try sending back Acct-Session-Id and User-Name in the Access-Accept (just set them to 'test') and see if either of them are altered in the Accounting-Request.  If they are, then there's something to work with, if they're not, then you're SOL.